# how can i generate C dependency files from header files

Tags: makefile

How can I generate C dependency files based on header files. Please note that I am not using GNU GCC. It is softune compiler for FR81S architecture and I do not have dependency generation option of any sort.  Also, I cannot add the include dependencies separately in makefiles because the number of dependent files may change any time.

What I want is that if I use the following c file

```
#include "abc.h"
int main(){return 0;}
```

and I make change in the `abc.h` how can makefile pick the change and compile my C file again.

Comment: You could still use gcc for dependency generation and your other compiler for actual compilation. Or makedepend.

Comment: what is makedepend??? i prefer no use of gcc at all

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend

Answer (score 0):

Check out the -HH option of the softune compiler.

In most cases, you will need to perform some post processing of the output.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are not doing anything unusual.  You can create the makefile manually.  For your example, this would address it properly.

```
main:  main.c abc.h
```

This says that main (or change it to whatever the target is called:  maybe it should be `main.exe` or `main.hex`) depends on the files `main.c` and `abc.h`.  If either changes, it should be recompiled.

Oddly, you don't want to use the GNU tools, so you can either write your own tool, or simply manually edit the makefile.

As a general rule, the dependency relationships of files tend to remain stable so once all the rules are created, it will be very easy to update them if needed.